# How can I check storage I have used on Google photos

Tags: google-photos

I know google photos is giving unlimited storage (for 16MP photos and 1020p videos). I have uploaded around 5000 photos and videos, but I cannot find the storage I have used.

Comment: Remember that is you backup photos in "high quality" they do not consume space from your Google Drive allocation, but do if you select "Original". Look in Photo - Settings - Backup & Sync fore this option and available space. Google does not breakdown cloud space used by type, it is all together.

Comment: Only @JellyTheBear's answer is useful (though getting the actual number by the suggested method can take a day or more). The other two answers say how to find out about the *paid-for* photo storage, which is not what the question is asking.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How to find storage requirements of your free Google Photos:

1. got to https://takeout.google.com/
2. pick only Photos for download
3. select parameters of the archive
4. wait for the process to finish (you will also get email)

You will then see the size of the archive(s) before downloading. As a bonus, you have now complete backup of your Google Photos.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the size of the compressed archive? I guess you'll have to download and extract the zips to get accurate size.

Comment: This works perfectly. It's slow and it took about 3 days to get the email with the results, but it allowed me to determine I am currently using 93 GB of photo storage, whereas the storage page says I'm using 1.5 GB, which is totally inaccurate. 
Zip files won't compress images  or videos, which are already compressed, so the estimates are accurate.

Comment: it gave the size of my photos with this approach in approx. 15 min (36 GB total photos&videos) it asks for dividing to zip files and there are options for 1, 2, 5, 10 GB for dividing

Answer (score 8):

Check here:
https://drive.google.com/settings/storage

There under "Total storage" you can see your used storage, and below when you click on "View details" you can see the details:

```
Storage details 

XX.XX GB used 
Drive   X GB 
Gmail   X GB 
Google Photos   X GB
```

Comment: Where's the details?  That is just an overview of each subsection, but if I click on Photos to see which photos are taking up how much, it doesn't show me.

Comment: Also, this doesn't tell you how much storage you are actually using in Google Photos, just how much you are using against your quota.

Comment: If you use Google Pixel with the unlimited upload of photos perk, you may find this number "inaccurate". My case: I've uploaded tons of photos in original quality and 4K videos, but this "Total storage" tells me that I've only used 0.79 GB of storage for Google Photos.

Answer (score 2):

It is available in google drive as well as from within the photos app.

**Photos App**

1. Open photos app.
2. From the side menu, tap on settings
3. Tap on Back up & sync
4. Here you'll find backup account details with the storage analytics.

---

**Google Drive**

1. Visit [drive.google.com](http://drive.google.com)
2. Click on the gear symbol at the top right. That's the settings
3. Under settings you'll find storage which should give you a fair
   estimate on how much storage space you've used and how much is
   remaining

If you need a breakdown of which google app is using how much storage,

1. Visit [drive.google.com](http://drive.google.com)
2. To the bottom left you'll have a notificiation that says - x GB / Y
   GB used.
3. Click on it and it gives you a breakdown where in you should be able
   to see how much data google photos is taking up.

Comment: it shows only google drive storage info, not google photos

Comment: Everything you ever store on google (be it photos or drive or gmail) is all a common cloud storage. Where exactly did you check? If you specifically only want to check the size occupied by photos in drive, the easiest way is from teh photos app itself.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly update photos app on playstore then,
Go to google photos app - - click on profile icon - - click on account storage option - - click on upload size - - there on the top you will xx storage out of 15gb used!!

Best luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Google very annoyingly refrains from revealing a list of *which* photos/videos count against your quota.

If it makes your blood boil, I'm with you.

The only tools that I've found (after searching for hours) are:

- https://photos.google.com/quotamanagement/large ("Only photos & videos that count towards your Google Account storage will appear here")

and

- https://photos.google.com/unsupportedvideos

But those do not fully address the question.